# Combine PostgreSQL query log

Tags: postgresql

I set PostgreSQL's `log_statement` setting to `all` for full query logging in the `data/postgresql.conf` file. While I like that the logs can be split in to separate days how can I combine all the queries being logged in to a single file called `queries.log`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the prefix on the existing log files in the configuration and was able to come up with the following...

```
log_filename = 'queries.log'
```